Can Razorpay Integration Be Achieved Entirely from the Frontend in a React.js Application, Considering CORS Limitations for Order Creation?
I'm currently working on integrating Razorpay into my React.js application, aiming for a frontend-only implementation. While most aspects of the payment process seem feasible to handle from the frontend, I've hit a roadblock regarding order creation due to CORS limitations.
It seems that making requests to the Razorpay API for order creation directly from the frontend is blocked by CORS policies while requesting using the fetch. function As a result, I'm unable to create orders without involving a backend server.
Has anyone successfully implemented Razorpay integration entirely from the frontend in a React.js application, overcoming the CORS restrictions for order creation? If so, could you please share your approach or any potential solutions to enable seamless payment processing without the need for a backend intermediary?
Any insights, experiences, or alternative strategies would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
